# Do you know any research on finding closed forms of recursively-defined sequences?

Tags: sequences-and-series, reference-request, recurrence-relations

I am dealing with a non standard progression and I had a hard time finding the general term $U_n = f(n)$ from the recursive definition: $U_{n+1} = b.a^{n+1} + a.U_{n}$

I would like to know if there exists any research in this domain. If so what are the keywords I can use to find the papers?

When I search, I always end up finding the geometric and the arithmetic progressions.

Comment: Have you studied sequence of functions?

Comment: Would be nice to have the domain and codomain of $g$.

Comment: The general term is usually called a "closed form", so searching for "closed form of recursive sequence" may help.

Comment: I am French, I was blindly translating the way we say it in France. Thank you!

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo I am not sure what you mean by domain and codomain, I would say $g:N->N§ I can write the formulation of g in the question

Comment: So, $g$ is linear?

Comment: These are called linear recurrence sequences, and there are [general linear algebra methods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation#Solving_via_linear_algebra) for solving them.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is an elementary problem, not a research topic. The recurrence is linear, and you begin by solving the homogeneous part,

$$U_{n+1}=aU_n,$$ that has the solution $U_n=ca^n$ where $c$ is an arbitrary constant.

Then as the RHS has the same shape as the homogeneous solution, you try the Ansatz $U_n=dna^n$:

$$U_{n+1}-aU_n=d(n+1)a^{n+1}-dna^{n+1}=ba^{n+1}$$ so that $d=b$.

The general solution is

$$U_n=(nb+c)a^n.$$

Comment: Nice way of solving it. It is indeed simple once I've read the solution :D

Comment: @PaulFournel: this is very similar to the resolution of a linear first order ODE. By the way, the Wikipedia article "Recurrence relation" gives you more than you need.

Comment: Is Ansatz used in English too?

Comment: @orange: yes it is, and it is regularly used on this site. Anyway, I have fixed the uppercase.

Comment: @YvesDaoust Funnily enough, I was about to lowercase it as I consider it a common word in mathematical English now, with no actual (vs. historial) relation to German.

Answer (score 2):

Search using phrases such as ["difference equations"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22difference+equations%22) and ["finite differences"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22finite%20differences%22) and ["nonlinear difference equations"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22nonlinear+difference+equations%22). [Dozens, perhaps hundreds of books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22difference+equations%22+archive.org) and tens of thousands of papers have been written on this topic in the past 300 some years. Indeed, George Boole (presently better known for Boolean logic stuff) wrote a well-known treatise on the subject in 1860 ([1880 3rd edition](https://archive.org/details/cu31924031240934/page/n5)).

Comment: Thx, this is what I was looking for!

Comment: I trust you when you say this is what I am searching for, but I am having a hard time seeing the link with my problem. I will read about it and then mark your answer green!

Comment: The given recurrence is linear. "nonlinear difference equations" seems misleading.

Comment: @Yves Daoust: You're correct. However, I wasn't sure how much beyond the specific example given the OP was interested in pursuing, and I wasn't sure to what extent simple searches for difference equations would lead to things besides finite linear difference equations, so I tossed in that link in a later edit for additional completeness. (FYI, I originally wrote this as a comment because I didn't want to get involved in details for something I haven't looked at in a while, but I decided to make it an answer because I probably make too many comments here that are really answers as it is.)